# Raspberry Pi 4 Qt6 Cross-Compile Setup error

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up for cross compilation of Qt6 between my Ubuntu machine and my Raspberry Pi 4 according to [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Cross-Compile_Qt_6_for_Raspberry_Pi) wiki page. I managed to get the process going up until the "build configuration file on qt-pibuild", which is after the `toolchain.cmake` document.

After I perform the `cmake --install . --parallel 4` command, the terminal return an error that I am not sure how to solve. I would appreciate to have any advice I can get on this issue

The error:

```
vboxuser@Utunubu:~/CrossPlatformQt/qt-pibuild$ cmake --build . --parallel 4
[532/9166] Linking CXX shared library qtbase/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6.4.0
FAILED: qtbase/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6.4.0 
: && /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-11 --sysroot=/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot -fPIC -I/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/include -pipe -O2  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed   -Wl,--version-script,/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/qt-pibuild/qtbase/src/dbus/DBus.version -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -shared -Wl,-soname,libQt6DBus.so.6 -o qtbase/lib/libQt6DBus.so.6.4.0 qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/DBus_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbus_symbols.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusabstractadaptor.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusabstractinterface.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusargument.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusconnection.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusconnectioninterface.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbuscontext.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbuserror.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusextratypes.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusintegrator.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusinterface.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusinternalfilters.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusintrospection.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusmessage.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusmetaobject.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusmetatype.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusmisc.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbuspendingcall.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbuspendingreply.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusreply.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusserver.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusservicewatcher.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusunixfiledescriptor.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusutil.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusvirtualobject.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusxmlgenerator.cpp.o qtbase/src/dbus/CMakeFiles/DBus.dir/qdbusxmlparser.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot:/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/qt-pibuild/qtbase/lib:  /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a  qtbase/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.4.0 && :
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-message.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `dbus_message_unref' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-message.o): in function `_dbus_message_loader_unref':
(.text+0x5b10): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-timeout.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_dbus_timeout_unref' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-timeout.o): in function `_dbus_timeout_list_free':
(.text+0x138): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-watch.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_dbus_watch_unref' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-watch.o): in function `_dbus_watch_list_free':
(.text+0x1b8): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): in function `_dbus_listen_systemd_sockets':
(.text+0x2510): undefined reference to `sd_listen_fds'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x2554): undefined reference to `sd_is_socket'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_dbus_fd_set_close_on_exec' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): in function `_dbus_fd_set_all_close_on_exec':
(.text+0x3e40): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-userdb.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_dbus_group_info_unref' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/vboxuser/CrossPlatformQt/rpi-sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-userdb.o): in function `_dbus_user_database_new':
(.text+0x4e8): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[535/9166] Building CXX object qtbase/...MakeFiles/Test.dir/qsignaldumper.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```